# $X,Y \sim Exp(1), X \perp Y$, joint density of $V = X, U = X/Y$

Tags: probability, random-variables, exponential-distribution, random-functions

I'd like to check if my results are correct. Could you guys please verify them?

$X,Y \sim \; Exp(1), X \perp Y$

Find the joint density of $U = X, V = X/Y$:

\begin{align}
V = X/Y & \rightarrow Y = U/V\\
U = X    & \rightarrow X = U \\
|Det(J)| &= U/V^{2} 
\end{align}where J is the jacobian matrix.

As long as they are iid,

$f_{Y}(U/V)f_{X}(U)|Det(J)| = e^{-U/V} e^{-U} \frac{U}{V^{2}}$

Comment: Please be **much more careful**, you cannot pass from one line to another from V=X to V=X/Y.

Comment: Oh my bad, it's a typo.